# Is this question NOT related to Angular?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

A user removed the *angular* tag in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539033/how-to-connect-two-directives-to-the-same-function-in-angular).

Am I blatantly missing something or what is this about?

Comment: And now they removed `[html]`. Don't understand it (I asked him to explain here)

Comment: The man deserves a meta-site all of his own.  Not that it will accomplish anything.  Two clicks is all it takes to roll it back, drama avoided.

Comment: @AlonEitan If it wouldn't be for the high rep of the user in question, I'd call BS and lack of competence on it. (Still - high rep isn't a guarantee, of course). I've asked him that too. Will be exciting to see the response. This far, I feel he might have misunderstood my issue.

Comment: @HansPassant I disagree. Simply rollback produces a quick result but with two drawbacks. 1. I haven't learned **if and how** I made a mistake. 2. My roll back got re-edited (improperly, I'd say) again. There's no drama, really. The point of Meta **is** to ask when uncertain in such cases, as far I'm informed.

Comment: Think the comment made by jonrsharpe should clear it up. I'd roll their edit back again. I doubt they will come here to explain.

Comment: And now I reported this edits war to a Moderator

Comment: @AlonEitan It escalated pretty quickly. :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten, on another note, looking at the link in the answer, at the top there is a SO question. Wouldn't it be worth marking your question a duplicate of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983140/is-there-a-way-to-bind-concisely-on-multiple-events-in-angular-2). I don't know enough to know if it is a duplicate but thought it would make sense if it was.

Comment: @Bugs Willing to consider that. However, I've been googling for the issue and haven't hit that link so it's a bit of a hard-to-stumble-upon, perhaps. Also, Angular2 is so rapidly evolving that the difference between Angular beta, ANgular RC and Angular 2.0 (and possibly Angular 2.4 too) are to be considered as different frameworks in some occasions. At any rate - it **might** be a dupe. Let me dwell on that (or let another user take the shot. I won't oppose).

Comment: @Bugs You're entirely correct. I changed my mind after re-reading the other question. I've duped-flagged my self now. First time ever! Whoohoo!

Comment: Don't engage in rollback wars. If someone is forcing a wrong edit for the second time, flag for a moderator.

Comment: @AndrasDeak At first I thought it was a misunderstanding. It took a few rounds before I realized the actual circumstances. Call me naive, hehe. Thanks for the point, though. I think the user's been reported by someone else, already.

Comment: Well a few rollbacks automatically raise a mod flag anyway. So the end result is the same, but you can spare bumping the question to the frontpage 15 times if you abort the war 2 steps in and raise a flag yourself. Oh, and you're naive ;)

Comment: I've seen this a few times, people removing all but the lowest level tag; e.g. "This question isn't about java its about the java mail api". Deeply unhelpful in my opinion but I expect that was the logic here. Not least because people often have "java" in their favourite tags not "every obscure tag under the sun"

Comment: @RichardTingle What? This is ridiculous. I'm following the `[php]` tag and would be annoyed to hear that removing it from questions considered as a valid edit. I can't follow every possible PHP related tags out there. They can edit and add more detailed tags, but should definitely not  remove it

Comment: Pooper?  Are you trying to say "Popper?"  As in, the rat goes in and something pops up?  Believe me, a rat going in a pooper would be an incredibly unfortunate situation.

Comment: @RichardTingle I think you meant “every obscure tag under the _oracle_”, didn't you?

Comment: The only tag I see someone removing several times is HTML. Why are you stating it's Angular tag?

Comment: You are missing something, how different is blatantly missing something than just missing something? I must be missing something.

Comment: @Braiam Because the question is about Angular. And I'm using HTML to express what I want to use as syntax. As for the removal, the user in question did remove that tag too at one point.

Comment: @DaveHorner You're obviously missing something. Blatantly! (Just kidding. I simply wanted to stress that it might be something very obvious that I'm missing despite it being right there in front of me. My attempt to be modest and not cut the violating user's head of.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I just noticed that you changed the title of my question to *AngularJS* and I'm curious about the reason. The question I'm referring to is about Angular (as in Angular 2 or 4 or whatever it's being called at the moment) not AngularJS (as in Angular 1.x or whatever...). Please explain in case I'm missing something.

Comment: @Braiam I noticed that you locked the post but the reference to this answer is questionable, in my opinion. I disagree with the reply below and it's not being accepted. In fact, that user seems to state that my original question is about AngularJS (which it isn't) making me suspect that he didn't really understand the issue. Please unlock and/or add the HTML tag as it's of importance to the question, as I see it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Braiam didn't lock any post. If your question is not about angular, how come you disagree with the original edit of removing it? You are contradicting yourself, this doesn't make any sense. The duplicate question you yourself linked to your question **is** about angular.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Both are your quotes: "@Braiam Because the question is about Angular." and "In fact, that user seems to state that my original question is about AngularJS (which it isn't)". Could you please not contradict yourself so blatantly?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: There's no contradiction. "AngularJS" refers to version 1 of the framework. "Angular" refers to version 2 and later of the framework. The question should be tagged with "angular".

Comment: the only remaining issue with this question is its use of obscene language: "I have a pooper... rat enters... rat leaves..." and "mouse enter pooper". who cares about the angular and html tags? seriously: there is an accepted answer by an angular gold badger, the post contains html source, so what?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Oh. Thanks. Ugh... why is it not named Angular-1 then... in any event, enough meta for me, I believe I've misunderstood enough stuff for one day.

Comment: I think you can add a comment to the edited question with an `@` of the user in question.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The question I asked **is** about Angular. Please read it properly before we can discuss it further. The tag **is** set correctly and the dupe-link **is** adequate. I'm not sure where you got that it isn't about Angular but I'm afraid that you're mistaken.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I have absolutely no desire to discuss this further, but I've explained in a comment sooner with quotes from your messages why I originally thought that. As I stated afterwards, I've been fooled by the very subtle difference of adding Js or not to the tag. You are welcome to read my comments.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I didn't find the comments you refer to but I trust your word. Anyway, you might be glad to learn that the difference between Angular and AngularJS is rather huge and profoundly groundbreaking. (Naming of the framework is intensely and terribly confusing, though - many been fooled including myself.) The regrettable part is that one of the mods refers to your answer from time of the previous ignorance of the JS-significance and bases his decision on "community call", which give the -8 and -14 is a flawed decision itself.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Indeed, I am well aware of the drastic differences between the two frameworks, I work with both on different projects on a daily fashion. What I was confused about, was the actual use of the tags. FTR, angular1 and angularx would be much more evident.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I have edited my answer to reflect my change of opinion and offer a try at consensus.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No problems, mate. Just glad that we finally come to a concensus. And I feel your pain (which reflects in the edit to your answer, meant a bit as a joke to lift the atmosphere around the issue, as it got a bit infected, hehe). I've been in that pain of total WTF'ness and confusion myself, just a few months back.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The issue's been resolved (please see the accepted answer). You can release the lock on the question, I believe.

Answer (score -4):

After much discussion and thoughts, I believe the question is related to both html and angular.

At its core however, it is related principally to HTML, as registering listeners is a basic html construct, and registering a single handler to multiple events in itself is not specific of any framework.

Adding the angular tag specifies that you are looking for angular related answers.

Hence, the removal of the tags **was** incorrect, and they should both be restored to the original state of the question.

---

<s>Gosh, is AngularJS vs Angular error prone...</s>
Gosh, is AngularJS vs Angular2 vs Angular 2 RC vs Angular error prone...

Comment: I think someone is mischaracterizing the issue. The only tag that is being removed several times is HTML. I think you didn't notice that when you answered.

Comment: No, I did not. In any event, the point expressed herein stands, the removal of html was correct. To be fair however, the [second revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43539033/2) *did* remove the angular tag. (right, you mention "removed several times")

Comment: @Braiam There's a removal of Angular tag as well. Take a look again, please. As for the tag suggestion, it's definitely not *AngularJS* because it's about Angular (i.e. Angular 2).

Comment: @KonradViltersten ONCE. That tag was removed ONCE. And is clear later on that what he wanted to remove is html one. Angular was most likely a mistake.

Comment: @Braiam There's a difference between *zero* and *one* and I'm not in a position to second-guess your point. As for the mistake part, I disagree with your opinion. That user hasn't explained much, haven't answered here and, frankly speaking, we can't really know their intentions. We can only state that his edit was invalid and that the whole thing got infected (as several users misunderstood naming etc.).

Comment: @KonradViltersten then, why were you rolling back the edit that removed html? Please explain? If you were not against that edit, why were you so hell bent on revert it?

Comment: @Braiam I **was** against the edit. I state that again and again. The tags should be *html* and *angular* and the user that you referred to to reply this question was ignorant of the difference between *angular* and *angularjs*, which is reflected in the score of **both** of his answers. I rolled back the edits to the original state and asked here to make sure I understand the issue. The way I see it, it's been kind of confirmed.

Comment: Both tags should be on. I'm not sure _why_ people are disagreeing with this to be honest but it would make more sense to have **both** tags. The comment made by jonrsharpe which has now been deleted made it clear that the OP is using Angular with HTML binding.

Comment: @Bugs well, the guy removing the html tag has a gold badge in angular and silver on html. Do you really believe he didn't have a **very good reason** to remote html? I mean, he should know whenever or not any of them is relevant. (BTW, as far I know, angular without html isn't as useful. Should all angular questions have the html tag, even when an html expert will not be able to answer the question?)

Comment: @Braiam in my opinion the OP is unsure if HTML is the cause of the issue and so _others_ may have the same view. That being the case the question is more searchable with the HTML tag than without it. It's not harming the site having the tag on and it's certainly not something someone should consider removing just because _they_ have knowledge. I'd understand if they'd also tagged the question using python or java etc. They are blatantly wrong.

Comment: @Bugs "OP is unsure if HTML" and there you have it. Is on experts hands, to decide whenever or not a tag is related to their expertise. We rely on experts for that same reason. Ask the one removing the tag for his reason. Don't simply ignore it for convenience sake.

Comment: @Braiam you missed the "...is the cause" from my quote. The question is to do with Angular with _HTML_ binding. Both are relevant to the question in my opinion and to not have the HTML tag on only hinders the question.

Comment: @Bugs angular without html doesn't do crap. Do you believe that html experts should have their tag poisoned with every angular question, or javascript question, or css question, or c#-mvc question, or any question that has *the most tangential relationship* with html? We don't want people using the ide tags for non-ide question, don't you believe this to be the same? Is the fact that it has html enough to keep the html tag? That's a leap logic right there, don't you agree?

Comment: @Braiam all else aside, no, the fact that it has html is not enough, it's the fact that the question is about a basic html element feature: registering handlers. I could actually ask that question without Angular context, and html and javascript would be the only two valid tags. Apart from this overlook, of course we don't want slightly tangential tags, but here, I believe html is not tangential, but instrumental of the question.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I don't know which question you are seeing, but as far I know the question boiled down is "bind multiple events at once in angular". There's nothing an html expert can help you with that.